# Não consigo acessar site servido pelo Grunt server de outro computador na LAN

Tags: javascript, grunt

Estou tentando acessar meu ambiente de desenvolvimento servido pelo Grunt e o site simplesmente não abre. É como se não existisse. Dentre outras features estou usando `livereload`, `jshint` e `karma` mas acho que o problema não está relacionado a isso.

Minhas configurações de servidor são:

```
// The actual grunt server settings
connect: {
  options: {
    port: 9010,
    hostname: 'localhost',
    livereload: 35729
  }
...
```

Answer (score 2):

**Este problema pode ser resolvido facilmente.**

Troque na sua configuração `arquivo Gruntfile.js` o seguinte:

De `hostname: 'localhost'`

Por `hostname: '0.0.0.0'`.

Quando você coloca `localhost` só é permitido endereço na faixa `127.0.0.*`.

Para usar endereços como `192.168.0.*` você deve especificar a outra mascara.

OBS: isso foi postado como erro no grpo de discussão do Grunt mas na verdade é apenas um problema de documentação que já foi resolvido nas versões mais novas.